# Stubbing out ajax requests with yeoman server

Tags: yeoman

When running `yeoman server` I want to be able to create URL stubs to simulate backend responses.

Take for example the following controller:

```
angularApp.controller('AppuserListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/admin/appuser/rest/?accept=json'})
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.page = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.error = data;
        });
});
```

This controller depends on an ajax request to retrieve a json  object to do any work. 
Is there a way to stub those out with `yeoman server` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend) to mock the $http object.

Comment: I'm talking about production code, not tests. 
What I opted for is CORS on the server side so I could use ajax requests with the actual backend. AFAIK there's no other way to develop with yeoman when using server side requests.